# How to make a oblique wing without areodynamics skill?

Tags: aerodynamics

Is it possible to make a oblique wing just by skewing a profile of a standard wing?

1. Take a wing profile from web
2. **Divide it in sagittal slices**
3. **Move slices along a new axis** (still lying on horizontal plane)
4. <s>Scale slices around wind direction to keep wing horizontal section of same surface</s>

Note that the slices, stay vertical. It Is a skew, not a rotation. Skewing means cutting the figure in infinitely many slices, and the translate vertically each slice. 
Like this

[image: pencils skewed to oblique arrangement, and straight pencils]

The drawing illustrates what I mean:
[image: sketch I did when trying to think on how to make a wing profile]

The 3 sketches are the wing, seen from above.

**Edit:**

I removed the scaling part, since skewing preserve surface, as long as width stay constant

[image: sketch file]

Comment: Can you explain step 3 better? I’m unclear on what you are asking.

Comment: is this a wing that will function at an extremely high angle of attack?  If so all the basic assumptions about airfoils would fail.

Comment: Since I don't know how to design a wing, i thought that maybe if I use a existing wing profile It can be converted to oblique with simple transformations. The step 3 is to make the supporting surface the same in spite of the skew.

Comment: Forget step 3 I just discovered the correction factor is almost 1 so I can just skip it.

Comment: What might I ask is the point? Skew wings are only of potential use a transonic speeds. Are you planning to adjust the skew angle during flight?  If so then just rotate the wing. If you want a fixed skew angle then give up since it’s a silly idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oblique winged aircraft have been investigated as demonstrated by the [NASA AD-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_AD-1). That said, the whole reason for an oblique wing arrangement is to provide good performance at both low speeds and at supersonic speeds. At low speeds a normal straight wing is best. At transonic speed and supersonic speeds, swept wings have advantages. An oblique wing only makes sense if the wing can be rotated from straight at low speeds to skewed at high speeds.

Not to be smug, but if you are asking this question, you aren't designing an airplane that is going to approach the speed of sound. For any practical homebuilt or model airplane, an oblique wing is going to perform less well than a straight wing even if you plan on rotating the wing. If you are planning on rotating the wing, then there is no particular reason the wing ribs need to be parallel to the airflow. The only effect of the "skewing" you are proposing is to make the airfoil section proportionally thinner as the thickness stays the same but the chord length increases.

In any case, questions about aviation and airplane design are better asked at https://aviation.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out also a number of specific terms that I have to learn to put to good use.

Answer (score 1):

You can make any thing you care to.

Question is what you want it to do.

Fly it won't.

But can you use it as a cream whipper or egg batter? Yes definitely.

Otherwise any surface called a wing has to follow certain rules to provide lift.

One of the most important ones is it can not have an angle of attack more than 16 degrees and that's the limit, preferably not more than 4-7 degrees.

The wing (airfoil) profiles have been engineered and tested in the wind tunnels to do their job most efficiently, such as the range of lift and speed, structural strength, aspect ratio, etc.

It is not advisable to tamper with them.

Comment: Yes the idea was to take well tested profiles and adapt them to become oblique wings. But doing so will change the angles longitudinally . I guess there is non chance I can design a oblique wing for flying without a wind tunnel or complex areodynamics right? And yes I intend to make it flying of course

Comment: Well forget my previous comment. Longitudinal angles will be the same. So Is there a chance that will work?

Comment: Wright brothers were the true frontier men of aviation. They had to explore, learn, and invent the science of flying. Look at the wings they designed. they establish the aspect ratio, cord length, and angle of attack of 3-5 degrees.

Comment: Well before creating a wing and wasting material, I was trying to seek if there wereajor mistakes that could result in epic failures, but I Guess everyone have to do epic failures lol. Thank you.

Comment: This answer is unnecessary negative. Oblique wing aircraft have been successfully flown.